# Extract one digit from every four digit in a sixteen digit integer and store in a variable in php

Tags: php, regex

I have generate a 16 digit number and i want to extract one number from every 4 digits of that 16 digit number. For e.g: 1234567892345678. I want to extract 2 from 1234, 7 from 5678, 3 from 9034 & 7 from 5678. Then store it in another variable $a. the extraction will be in a random manner.

Comment: 2 from 9034?? tell use the pattern by which you want to extract numbers

Comment: I have no clue how to code this thing. Completely blank.

Comment: please saw what u try then we help you

Comment: Add the code you have tried & explain the pattern you are expecting to follow for single digits.

Comment: Do you want to extract any random numbers from those 4 digits or in a pattern?

Comment: I want to extract it in a random pattern.

Comment: This question is quite random...

Comment: If the randomness is important, you should explicitely state it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$d = '1234567892345678';

$s = str_split($d, 4); // split in 4 digits

$n = array_map(function($x) {
    return substr($x, rand(0, 3), rand(1, 1)); // extract single digit random number
}, $s);
```

`$n` will hold the random numbers.

Comment: You'll need to typecast the string as number again if you need it as number

Comment: PHP will automatically cast it to number.

Comment: Just wrap the array_map inside an implode and you got it.

Comment: This is what the OP means by his question. +1 for you!

Comment: $string[rand(0,3)].$string[rand(4,7)].$string[rand(8,11)].$string[rand(12,15)];

Comment: @RobQuist :).. Just figured it out by chance.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late at answering this question but you can simply use `strlen` function along with `for` loop like as

```
$str = "1234567892345678";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str);$i += 4){
    echo $str[$i+rand(0,3)];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you have a one-liner:

```
$s = $string[rand(0,3)].$string[rand(4,7)].$string[rand(8,11)].$string[rand(12,15)];
echo $s;
```

Another one-liner:

```
for($s='',$i=0;$i<10; $s.=$string[rand($i,$i+=3)]);  
echo $s;
```

Comment: He doesnt want to delete digits, he wants to extract 4 digits and save that 4 digit number in a variable

Comment: Ok, now it is fixed.

Comment: It will always extracting the 3rd digit. Not random.

Comment: You didn't say anything in your question about randomness.